# Get a hold of an object (function of controller, service or directive) from another module

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

Is it possible to access functions that sit either in the same module or in a different one?

Something like:

```js
var fooDir = angular.module("directives").get("foo")
```

… or:

```js
var myCtrl = angular.module("app").controllers["myCtrl"]
```

I guess for services we can use an injector:

```js
inj = angular.injector(['myServicesModule'])
$myService = inj.get('$myService')
```

… but will it work for controllers and directives?

Answer (score 16):

### Get the injector

#### Injector from modules

For example, to get the injector of an empty and not attached to DOM application instance, assuming you have your own module `test`:

```
angular.injector(['ng', 'test']);
```

#### Injector from existing app

For example, to get the injector of the application managing a selected node with id `test`:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('test')).injector();
```

### Get an instance from the injector

Assuming you get the injector as the `injector` variable

#### Get a service instance

To get the `$rootScope` instance:

```
injector.get('$rootScope');
```

#### Get a controller instance

Assuming you get a controller named `TestCtrl`:

```
injector.get('$controller')('TestCtrl', { $scope: {} });
```

#### Get an element with a directive compiled

Assuming you have a directive test, to get the compiled element against `$rootScope`:

```
injector.get('$compile')('<div a/>')(injector.get('$rootScope'));
```

### Helpers from angular jqLite or jQuery

Besides `injector` to get the injector of a jqLite or jQuery collection, you can, assuming a jqLite or jQuery collection wrapping an attached DOM element which exists in your application, as variable `$element`:

#### Get the controller instance attached to DOM element

```
$element.controller();
```

#### Get the scope instance attached to DOM element

```
$element.scope();
```

#### Get the isolate scope instance attached to DOM element

```
$element.isolateScope();
```

#### Get the hidden data attached by angular to DOM element

```
$element.inheritedData();
```

> Moreover, each time what you get is an instance of a JavaScript constructor (services, controllers), you can get this constructor using the `constructor` property of the instance.

### List of registered services, controllers, etc.

There is no exposed list of registered services, controllers, etc. You can, however, override providers methods, to get, for example, the registrations occuring on top of module 'ng':

```
angular.module('ng').config(
    function ($provide, $compileProvider, $controllerProvider) {
      
        angular.forEach(['service', 'provider', 'controller'], function (m) {
            var _m = $provide[m];
            $provide[m] = function () {
                console.log('$provide', m, arguments);
                return _m.apply($provide, arguments);
            };
        });

        angular.forEach(['directive'], function (m) {
            var _m = $compileProvider[m];
            $compileProvider[m] = function () {
                console.log('$compileProvider', m, arguments);
                return _m.apply($compileProvider, arguments);
            };
        });
      
        angular.forEach(['register'], function (m) {
            var _m = $controllerProvider[m];
            $controllerProvider[m] = function () {
                console.log('$controllerProvider', m, arguments);
                return _m.apply($controllerProvider, arguments);
            };
        });
      
    });
```

This way you can get your own lists. But it's called overriding the framework and you should not do that.

Comment: Instead of angular.element(document.getElementById('test')).injector(); should be angular.element('#test').injector()

Comment: @YuraZaletskyy using selectors only works if jQuery is loaded, otherwise it uses jqLite and it throws this error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/jqLite/nosel